# PostgreSQL - ALTER column data type from integer to integer array

Tags: postgresql, type-conversion

Kindly help to modify a column of type integer to integer array:

I had created a table with a column `content_id` of type integer. then I tried to change the `content_id(integer)` to `integer[](integer array)` but its showing error as displayed:

```
TestDatabase=# ALTER TABLE tbl_handset_content ALTER COLUMN content_id TYPE integer[];
ERROR:  column "content_id" cannot be cast to type "pg_catalog.int4[]"
```

Regards,

Sravan

Answer (score 41):

Try this (column test_id is of type INTEGER before alter takes place). PostgreSQL 8.4.

```
ALTER TABLE test.test_id
    ALTER COLUMN test_id TYPE INTEGER[]
    USING array[test_id]::INTEGER[];
```

Comment: How would you alter the type the other direction? INTEGER[] to INTEGER? Say, for example, I only want to preserve the first element.

Comment: To migrate back using the first element would be something like: ```ALTER TABLE test.test_id ALTER COLUMN test_id TYPE INTEGER USING test_id[1]::INTEGER;``` Note that arrays are 1-indexed by default.

Comment: For some servers, instead of `INTEGER[]` you can try `_int` or `_int4` or `_int8`, as it suits you. `_` implies an array data type

Answer (score 7):

This worked better for me!

```
ALTER TABLE schema.table
    ALTER COLUMN column
    DROP DEFAULT;
ALTER TABLE schema.table
    ALTER COLUMN column TYPE INTEGER[]
    USING array[column]::INTEGER[];
ALTER TABLE schema.table
    ALTER COLUMN column SET DEFAULT '{}';
```

Comment: If you get an n-dimensional array (and doesn't want that) 

    update table set colum = array(select e from unnest(column) u(e));

Comment: Except that it didn't work for me. But please enlighten us with your insight?